# Why is lighttpd saying "unknown config-key: accesslog.filename"?

Tags: webserver, lighttpd

I have created a simply vhost on Lighttpd web server and put these lines on the .conf file.

```
server.errorlog                = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
accesslog.filename             = "/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"
```

I have read error.log and I found this:

```
2011-04-22 00:36:58: (server.c.954) WARNING: unknown config-key: accesslog.filename (ignored)
```

How is it possible? `accesslog.filename` exists, it's an option of the server.

I found it on their website: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Docs:ConfigurationOptions

What can I do?

Answer (score 19):

The option `accesslog.filename` is for the [`mod_accesslog`](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Docs%3aConfigurationOptions#mod_accesslog-access-log-files) module, so you need to load that module.

```
server.modules += ( "mod_accesslog" )
```

Comment: Appreciated too! I was googling for this just a minute ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this issue for Lighttpd on your router (with Entware packages) check that this module was installed at all.

1) connect to your router via ssh and than execute the command:

```
opkg list-installed
```

2) should be line with "lighttpd-mod-accesslog - 1.4.xx". If it is not installed, install it:

```
opkg install lighttpd-mod-accesslog
```

3) adjust (change) your lighttpd.conf file with adding this module and config-key:

```
server.modules = (
"mod_redirect",
...
"mod_accesslog",
)

...
accesslog.filename          =  "/opt/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"
```

4) restart Lighttpd:

```
/opt/etc/init.d/S80lighttpd restart
```

These steps helped me. *Also I created access.log file before config manipulation*